# Flutter: Getting file content from Google Drive

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, readonly

I'm trying to get file bytes of a file that I have on Google Drive but I ran into a problem. I successfully created credentials and added needed permissions like it is stated in the official documentation, but I'm having a problem with getting bytes of the file so I can read its content.

```
static Future<String> loadAsset() async { return await rootBundle.loadString("assets/service_account_key.json"); }

  static isNewVersionAvailable() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    var credentialsContent = await loadAsset();
    
    final credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(json.decode(credentialsContent));

    final httpClient = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']);

    final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(httpClient);

    final streamController = StreamController<List<int>>();

    const fileId = 'ID_OF_MY_FILE'; 

    final response = driveApi.files.export(fileId, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', downloadOptions: drive.DownloadOptions.fullMedia);
```

But on the last line I got this error while debugging:

```
<Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

Is there any way to read data content from file?